# CLI command to print sheet2 from libreoffice calc .ods

Tags: linux, command-line, printing, libreoffice-calc

Is there a commandline option to print sheet2 from file.ods using the terminal?
I tried loffice, localc, lp, lpr and am unable to specify the precise sheet I want to print. Any ideas on this?

Comment: AFAIK there's currently no way to do this. If you know the page range, you may use [unoconv](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/doc2odt.1.html) to create a pdf containing just that specific range. There's a [unoconv feature request to spoecify calc sheets for output](https://github.com/unoconv/unoconv/issues/34), but it's inactive since four years :-|

Comment: Maybe this answer can help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1042624/how-to-split-an-ods-spreadsheet-file-into-csv-files-per-sheet-on-the-terminal